# Query Tables for STRPDM columns

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm new to DB2. Is there a way to query the tables to it will display the same data that STRPDM displays for a printed report (i.e.): Member, Type, Creation Date, Last Changed Date, Time, Records, Deleted Records, Text?

I'm not a DBA, but I have access to the SYSIBM schema (since I'm on the data team). I poked around the site and couldn't find a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

Most of what you want is available in [SYSPARTITIONSTAT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcatsyspstat.htm?lang=en).  The way that source members are stored is unique to IBM i, and they aren't really a DB2 construct as such, although DB2 for i does keep limited information about source members modelled as partitions.

The IBM i way to get access to that information is through the [RTVMBRD](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/rtvmbrd.htm?lang=en) CL command or equivalent API.  You can also see that via the DSPFD TYPE(*MBRLIST) command, which you can dump to a file via the OUTFILE() parameter and then query via SQL...

Comment: Thanks so much Buck that was extremely helpful! Now that I can see this information it opens up another plethora of questions. One odd result from running this. There is a table listed multiple times (over 100+), with no rows, never used. Just running a simple select on SYSPARTITIONSTAT. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, without seeing what table you're talking about I can only guess.  Is the library / schema QSYS?  And the file / table something like Q04079N223?  If so, you are looking at IBM i internal storage for spooled printer reports.  The operating system allocates these members as needed, and clears them when done.  Clearing a member sets NUMBER_ROWS to zero.

Comment: No. The name was actually kind of normal. I grabbed a senior developer and asked if he recognized the tables. He told me they're "member" tables. Learning something every day. :-) Thanks again!